# Java and its signed bytes: Sending hex information via UDP possible?

Tags: udp, hex, rtp, unsigned

I am currently working on an application to change my RGBWW light strips by a Java application.

Information has to be sent via UDP packages in order to be understood by the controller.

Unfortunately, the hex number 0x80 has to be sent - which is causing some problems.

Whenever I send a byte array containing only numbers fron 0x00 to 0x79 (using DataPacket and a DataSocket), I do get an UDP Package popping up on my network monitor.
As soon as I include the number 0x80 or any other higher, I see two things Happen:

1: I do not longer get only UDP protocols, but messages are displayed as RTP / RTCP most of the time

2: The method Integer.hexToString() does not display "80", but gives me a "ffffff80".

My question: Is there something I am missing when it comes to sending hex info by UDP? Or is there another way of sending it, possibly avoiding the annoyingly signed bytes?

I unfortunately did not find any information that would have significantly helped me on that issue, but I hope you can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hex is a representation. There is no such thing as hex data. There is binary data. The fact that Java's bytes are signed doesn't change what's in the bits. The argument to `Integer.toHexstring()` is an `int`, so 0x80 got promoted and sign-extended.